# How do I move the Launcher to the bottom?

Tags: 16.04, launcher

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, it's as new as I can get without the PC running slow (old computer lol) and I like Ubuntu, but the only thing that bugs me is where the launcher is, I'd like to move the launcher down to the bottom, kinda like Windows, and again I can only us Ubuntu 16.04 because if I us 18.04 it starts running really really slow. If there's not a way I'll eventually get over it. But I would like to move the Launcher to the bottom, I don't mind it if it's a terminal command(as long as you go step by step) or through something else, it's just annoying and seems like it's faster if I move it to the bottom. Thank you to all who's willing to answer my question.

Comment: Are you  using Unity (or Gnome) since you talk about Launcher (not Dock)?  Check this tutorial: https://www.howtogeek.com/251616/how-to-move-the-unity-desktops-launcher-to-the-bottom-of-your-screen-on-ubuntu-16.04/

Answer (score 0):

Run in a terminal

`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom`

After it moves to bottom you may need to r. click on the Desktop > Organize Desktop by Name to move any Desktop icons off of the launcher (if any..

To go back to orig replace Bottom with Left in command